# Why do I get a 419 page when I have my token added?

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I have a blog post that I want to edit in its own view, yet when I put the edits to change, I get a 419 page.

This is my edit view to edit the blog in question specified by its id :

```
<div id="body" style="color:#333">
    <h1 style="color:#333">Update blog</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="{{route('blogSingle',$blog->id)}}">
        @method('put')
        @csrf
        <div class="field">
            <label for="title" class="label" style='font-size:1.2rem'>Title</label>

            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Blog Title" value="{{$blog->title}}">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="body" class="label" style='font-size:1.2rem'>Body</label>

            <div class="control">
                <textarea type="text" class="textarea" name="body" id="body" placeholder="Blog Description">{{$blog->body}}</textarea>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="field is-grouped">
            <div class="control">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I've also a view for every single blog, and in it, I click on a button to redirect to a blog edit view like so :

```
<div id="body">
    {{-- Add a variable blog post here --}}
    <h1><span>blog single post</span> <span><a href="{{route('blog-edit',$blog->id)}}" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit Blog</a></span></h1>
    <div>
        <img src="images/grew-a-mustache.jpg" alt="Mustache">
        <div class="article">
            <h2 class="lead">{{$blog->title}}</h2>
            <p class="lead">
                {{$blog->body}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My routes involved are as the following :

```
Route::get('blog-single/{blog}',[BlogController::class,'show'])->name('blogSingle');
Route::get('blog-single/{blog}/edit', [BlogController::class, 'edit'])->name('blog-edit');
Route::put('blog-single/{blog}',[BlogController::class, 'update']);
```

Why am I still getting a 419 page expired? I even inspected the page before send and I see my token clearly right here :
[image]

Comment: Did you wait a lot on that page? 419 means the auth expired.

Comment: I made the edits almost instantly, just to test if it works. However, I added the articles yesterday from a create-blog view which is dedicated for creating a new blog and it first had the @csrf inserted. I'm not sure if it counts.

Comment: Could you try replacing `@method('put')` with `@method('PUT')`?

Comment: I just did, yet I still get the same thing. I've added SESSION_DOMAIN yesterday to my env file with the domain of 127.0.01:8000. I added it because while I was trying to create a new blog, I was also getting a 419 page expired and that was when I first added the @csrf in my create blog view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 419 is only thrown when the [VerifyCsrfToken](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.html) middleware fails to validate your token. Having `@csrf` is not a guarantee that your token won't fail. Reasons your token might fail:

- Your session has a different token; check the result of `session()->token()` and see if it matches with the token in the `@csrf` field. If it does not, try `session()->flush()` and re-authenticate if you have to.
- You have another form input with `_token` as name after the `@csrf` which overwrites the CSRF
- You have middleware manipulating the token
- You have messed with the vendor file, and so the `tokensMatch` function isn't functioning as it should (If you think you have done this, you can delete your vendor folder, then run `composer clearcache` and `composer install`)

I would like to add, you're not routing to your update method:

`<form method="POST" action="{{route('blogSingle',$blog->id)}}">`

is calling the show method:

`Route::get('blog-single/{blog}', [BlogController::class,'show'])->name('blogSingle');`

This *does* work, since you're specifying the method and the URL is the same, but this is not good practice. It'd be better if you explicitly call the update route (which you haven't even given a name yet). It's also better practice to use the placeholder names instead of letting the route fill the placeholders in order:

`Route::put('blog-single/{blog}',[BlogController::class, 'update'])->name('blog-update');`

`<form method="POST" action="{{route('blog-update', ['blog' => $blog])}}">`

You can also use [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) to quickly bind the blog to the placeholder.